# Datasets in Biodomain like Word similarity datasets used in word2vec and Glove

Tags: nlp, bioinformatics, text-mining, biopython

I am training word2vec on biomedical texts. In order to perform word similarity and word analogy tests I want to have pairs of biomedical terms having same relationships(could be any), just like we have a comprehensive list of City-State data in word2vec. I tried searching the web but since I am new to the domain I am finding it confusing.

So, where can I find the list relevant to Drug-gene or Protein-action, etc? Or how can I mine this data. Please suggest publicly available such datasets. Also, please suggest any additional interesting relationships which I can also query.

Another way would be to use available ontologies as they include relations between concepts such as has-part, is-a-way-of-doing, is-a-cause-of, is-a-symptom-of etc. Can I use ontologies to extract such pairs? If yes, then what ontologies and how?

Are there any gold standard datasets already available that can serve my purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, where can I find the list relevant to Drug-gene or Protein-action,
>   etc?

Have a look at ChEMBL, e.g. [aspirin](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/chembl/compound/inspect/CHEMBL25) is linked to its target [cyclooxygenase](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/chembl/target/inspect/CHEMBL2094253)

> Another way would be to use available ontologies as they include
>   relations between concepts such as has-part, is-a-way-of-doing,
>   is-a-cause-of, is-a-symptom-of etc. Can I use ontologies to extract
>   such pairs? If yes, then what ontologies and how?

A good start is the [ChEBI ontology](http://www.ebi.ac.uk/chebi/init.do).